# How to use different address for pop.gmail.com

Tags: email, proxy, smtp, gmail, pop3

I've been searching for a way to hide the gmail server name (pop.gmail.com and smtp.gmail.com). I want the email client (outlook) to point to our own server (say, pop.myserver.com), which in the end route to the real server. I tried the DNS CN record but it causes certificate warning.

Are there any ways to enable this? Is it possible using stunnel? Any proxy/relay/anything to make it work? Is it possible to be done on simply a shared web server (those provided by hostgator, or godaddy)?

Comment: First, why are you trying to do this? Tell us why, and maybe there is a better way we can guide you to. Second, who are you trying to hide the names from?: Your internal users or external users (in the header information)? Lastly, when you say "I want the email client (outlook) to point to our own server (say, pop.myserver.com)", do you mean an actual physical server, or to your DNS name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear why you would want to do what your asking.

But one solution would be to use fetchmail (http://fetchmail.berlios.de/). You could install fetchmail on your own server and it would retrieve the mail from the upstream pop/imap server. You would also need to configure a local MTA and pop/imap client, do handle the delivery and local access to the mail. Probably the most popular for these are Postfix and Dovecot, though there are other options.

Configuring all of the above requires a significant amount of work and you will need full access to the server not just a shared web service.

Comment: The bad things is the web server part. If only I can own an online webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your own server to perform POP-retrieves from Google and then have the users point their POP clients at your server. It can also double-duty for SMTP as well.

Comment: The bad thing is I need my own server.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately pop.gmail.com simply refers to an IP (or several in this case). I'd guess that if you set up the same IPs in the DNS of your own subdomain (pop.myserver.com) it would also work. Of course, they would be aliases of the Google IPs from that point on, so you will not be able to use them for referring to your own server. But that seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: I really want to avoid using IP address, that's why I tried using the CN record at the first place. I wanted to maximize the google cdn capabilities.